# How to explode multiple columns, different types and different lengths?

Tags: python, pyspark

I've got a DF with columns of different time cycles (1/6, 3/6, 6/6 etc.) and would like to "explode" all the columns to create a new DF in which each row is a 1/6 cycle.

```
from pyspark import Row 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, arrays_zip, col

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('DataFrame') \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], c=[11, 22, 33], d=['foo'])])

|  a|                 b|           c|    d|
+---+------------------+------------+-----+
|  1|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|[11, 22, 33]|[foo]|
+---+------------------+------------+-----+
```

I'm doing the explode:

```
df2 = (df.withColumn("tmp", arrays_zip("b", "c", "d"))
       .withColumn("tmp", explode("tmp"))
       .select("a", col("tmp.b"), col("tmp.c"), "d"))
```

But the output is not what I want:

```
|  a|  b|   c|    d|
+---+---+----+-----+
|  1|  1|  11|[foo]|
|  1|  2|  22|[foo]|
|  1|  3|  33|[foo]|
|  1|  4|null|[foo]|
|  1|  5|null|[foo]|
|  1|  6|null|[foo]|
+---+---+----+-----+
```

I would want it to look like this:

```
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1| 11|foo|
|   |  2|   |   |
|   |  3| 22|   |
|   |  4|   |   |
|   |  5| 33|   |
|   |  6|   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

I am new to Spark and from the start I've got complicated topics ! :)

**Update 2019-07-15**: Maybe someone has a solution without usage of UDFs? -> answered by @jxc

**Update 2019-07-17**: Maybe someone has a solution how to change the null <-> values sequences in more complicated order? Like in `c` - `Null, 11, Null, 22, Null, 33` or more complex situation as we want in column `d` first value to be `Null`, next `foo` then `Null, Null, Null`:

```
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|   |   |
|   |  2| 11|foo|
|   |  3|   |   |
|   |  4| 22|   |
|   |  5|   |   |
|   |  6| 33|   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way without using udf:

**UPDATE on 2019/07/17:** adjusted SQL stmt and added  N=6 as parameter to SQL.

**UPDATE on 2019/07/16:** removed the temporary column `t`, replaced with a constant `array(0,1,2,3,4,5)` in the **transform** function. In such case, we can operate on the value of the array elements directly instead of their indexes.

**UPDATE:** I removed the original method which uses String functions and converts data types in the array elements all into String and less efficient. The Spark SQL higher-order functions with Spark 2.4+ should be better than the original method.

### Setup

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([ Row(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], c=['11', '22', '33'], d=['foo'], e=[111,222]) ])

>>> df.show()
+---+------------------+------------+-----+----------+
|  a|                 b|           c|    d|         e|
+---+------------------+------------+-----+----------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|[11, 22, 33]|[foo]|[111, 222]|
+---+------------------+------------+-----+----------+

# columns you want to do array-explode
cols = df.columns

# number of array elements to set
N = 6
```

### Using SQL higher-order function: [transform](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/16/introducing-new-built-in-functions-and-higher-order-functions-for-complex-data-types-in-apache-spark.html)

Use the Spark SQL higher-order function: transform(), do the following:

1. create the following Spark SQL code where **`{0}`** will be replaced by the column_name, **`{1}`** will be replaced by **`N`**:

   ```
   stmt = '''
      CASE
         WHEN '{0}' in ('d') THEN
           transform(sequence(0,{1}-1), x -> IF(x == 1, `{0}`[0], NULL))
         WHEN size(`{0}`) <= {1}/2 AND size(`{0}`) > 1 THEN
           transform(sequence(0,{1}-1), x -> IF(((x+1)*size(`{0}`))%{1} == 0, `{0}`[int((x-1)*size(`{0}`)/{1})], NULL))
         ELSE `{0}`
       END AS `{0}`
   '''
   ```

   **Note:** array transformation only defined when array contains more than one (unless specified in a separate `WHEN` clause) and **`<= N/2`** elements (in this example, `1 < size <= 3`). arrays with other size will be kept as-is.
2. Run the above SQL with **selectExpr()** for all required columns

   ```
   df1 = df.withColumn('a', F.array('a')) \
           .selectExpr(*[ stmt.format(c,N) for c in cols ])

   >>> df1.show()
   +---+------------------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
   |  a|                 b|               c|          d|              e|
   +---+------------------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
   |[1]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|[, 11,, 22,, 33]|[, foo,,,,]|[,, 111,,, 222]|
   +---+------------------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
   ```
3. run **arrays_zip** and **explode**:

   ```
   df_new = df1.withColumn('vals', F.explode(F.arrays_zip(*cols))) \
               .select('vals.*') \
               .fillna('', subset=cols)

   >>> df_new.show()
   +----+---+---+---+----+
   |   a|  b|  c|  d|   e|
   +----+---+---+---+----+
   |   1|  1|   |   |null|
   |null|  2| 11|foo|null|
   |null|  3|   |   | 111|
   |null|  4| 22|   |null|
   |null|  5|   |   |null|
   |null|  6| 33|   | 222|
   +----+---+---+---+----+
   ```

   **Note**: `fillna('', subset=cols)` only changed columns containing Strings

### In one method chain:

```
df_new = df.withColumn('a', F.array('a')) \
           .selectExpr(*[ stmt.format(c,N) for c in cols ]) \
           .withColumn('vals', F.explode(F.arrays_zip(*cols))) \
           .select('vals.*') \
           .fillna('', subset=cols)
```

### Explanation with the transform function:

The transform function (list below, reflect to an old revision of requirements)

```
transform(sequence(0,5), x -> IF((x*size({0}))%6 == 0, {0}[int(x*size({0})/6)], NULL))
```

As mentioned in the post, **`{0}`** will be replaced with column name. Here we use column-`c` which contains 3 elements as an example:

- In the transform function, `sequence(0,5)` creates a constant array `array(0,1,2,3,4,5)` with 6 elements, and the rest sets the lambda function with  one argument `x` having the value of elements.
- **IF(condition, true_value, false_value)**: is a standard SQL function
- The condition we applied is: **`(x*size(c))%6 == 0`** where `size(c)=3`, if this condition is true, it will return **c[int(x*size(c)/6)]**, otherwise, return **NULL**. so for `x` from 0 to 5, we will have:

  ```
  ((0*3)%6)==0) true   -->  c[int(0*3/6)] = c[0]
  ((1*3)%6)==0) false  -->  NULL
  ((2*3)%6)==0) true   -->  c[int(2*3/6)] = c[1]
  ((3*3)%6)==0) false  -->  NULL
  ((4*3)%6)==0) true   -->  c[int(4*3/6)] = c[2]
  ((5*3)%6)==0) false  -->  NULL
  ```

Similar to column-e which contains a 2-element array.

Comment: Great explanation, a bit tricky on the "t" column, but wow, nice way to do it!

Comment: could you explain the `transform(t, (x,i) -> IF((i*size({0}))%6 == 0, {0}[int(i*size({0})/6)], NULL))` more deeply? Thanks!

Comment: @cincin21, added explanation to the transform function.

Comment: Great work, will surely help me in my mission to learn pyspark! Best!

Comment: @cincin21, just curious, is the solution worked for your task or anything wrong?

Comment: it works in the example as it should work, I will have to rebuild the solution to handle more split cases etc. but it will take some time to finish :) I will additionally have to read on the Spark's `null` values to figure out if or not to use `.fillna('', subset=cols)` in the code.

Comment: @fathomson, with Spark 2.4+, we got many new useful functions to operate on arrays and maps. we will have to dig and test more to find their full potentials.: )

Comment: @jxc is it possible to implement some `RANGE` instead of `array(0,1,2,3,4,5)` ? Later I would like to create bigger queries with array 0 to 60 :)

Comment: @jxc Another question: how to create a column which starts with null like column "e" for example would be: `null, null, 111, null, null, 222` ?

Comment: @cincin21, you can use **`sequence(0,5)`** to replace `array(0,1,2,3,4,5)`, see my post, section "As a side note". To create a null column, just use **F.lit()**, for example: `df.withColumn('e', F.lit(None))`. not sure about the `222` in your list. data in spark are not sorted by index. the first or last row retrieved from a distributed system could be well different on different queries?

Comment: @cincin21, BTW. you might want to add backticks to enclose the column names `{0}` in the variable `stmt` in case there are white spaces or other meta characters in the column names.

Comment: @jxc Thank you, my second question regards the transformation process in the main answer. So in `e` column first we had `[111,222]` values. After the `transformation` and before the `explode` it was `[111,,, 222,,]` so my question is how to create the transformation of column `e` to get `[,,111,,,222]` . Hope it makes sens to you :)

Comment: @cincin21, check this: `df.selectExpr('e','transform(sequence(0,5), x -> IF(((x+1)*size({0}))%6 == 0, {0}[int((x-1)*size({0})/6)], NULL)) as e1'.format('e')).show()`

Comment: @cincin21, as the lambda function in `transform()` is basically manipulating SQL statements, you can write nested WHEN/CASE statements or IF function to handle different configurations.

Comment: @cincin21, for column-d: df.selectExpr('d','transform(sequence(0,5), x -> IF(x == 1, d[0], NULL)) as d1').show()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196579/discussion-between-cincin21-and-jxc).

Answer (score 2):

To get to your output you would have to change col a to an array and insert empty values to the c array.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, arrays_zip, col, array

def fillArrayVals(a):
  for i in [1,3,5]:
    a.insert(i,None)
  return a

fillArrayValsUdf = udf(fillArrayVals, ArrayType(IntegerType(), True))    

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], c=[11, 22, 33], d=['foo'])])
df = df.withColumn("a", array(col("a"))).withColumn("c", updateArrayUdf("c"))
df = df.withColumn("tmp", arrays_zip("a","b", "c", "d"))\
   .withColumn("tmp", explode("tmp"))\
   .select(col("tmp.a"), col("tmp.b"), col("tmp.c"), col("tmp.d"))
```

The code above results in, you could cast to string to show empty values instead of null

```
+----+---+----+----+
|   a|  b|   c|   d|
+----+---+----+----+
|   1|  1|  11| foo|
|null|  2|null|null|
|null|  3|  22|null|
|null|  4|null|null|
|null|  5|  33|null|
|null|  6|null|null|
+----+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Good idea, but maybe there is a solution without udf's, because when working with millions of rows it is suggested to avoid those?

Comment: Hi @fathomson, I'm trying to execute the code but first I've also have to add `from pyspark.sql.functions import udf` but still not sure how to import the `updateArray`?

Comment: Hi @cincin21, there was an error in the provided code snipped. updateArray is renamed with fillArrayVals which is the included function